# JetBrains Rider: error: ASP.NET Core IIS Module is not found. Check the IIS Express settings

Tags: .net, .net-core, jetbrains, rider, kestrel

Уважаемые господа,

когда я создаю простой проект типа NET Core WEB api (dotnet new webapi) - то при попытке запустить его в JetBrains Rider я получаю ошибку "ASP.NET Core IIS Module is not found. Check the IIS Express settings".

При этом я вообще стараюсь использовать Kestrel:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(so =>
    {
        so.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 10;
        so.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 10;
        so.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800;
        so.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
    });
```

я довольно быстро нагуглил статью на сайте джетбрейнс, которая [говорит](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Running_IISExpress.html) "а! чувак! так у тебя нет IIS express!" - и объясняет, как его установить.

я не хотел бы ставить на свою машину этот IIS Express, если это возможно.

Но вот вопрос: как бы настроить Rider так, чтобы можно было запускать проект в отладке и т.п., но не получать этой ошибки?

Comment: в правом верхнем углу попытайтесь выбрать не IIS Express, а "<название проекта> http" и запустить, должно запуститься как self-hosted

Comment: @ExplodingKitten - спасибо за совет, я пока еще новичок в Rider, но вроде разобрался. На днях постараюсь написать расширенный ответ на свой вопрос...